# How to use this. on a Functional Component on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

Guys I'm new to react and trying to understand some things, I did a search on the web and I'm not sure if I can achive what I Want 
I have a functional component on react, that is working perfeclty fine, but I need to validation a lot of fields,
I try to use some libraries out there and end with this https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-react-validator

but the examples use this. to get to work, 
But I don't know if I can use this on a functional component I'm trying but it's not working.
Is there any way to use this.? or to make this library work on my project?

I Tried this:

```
  function constructor() {
    this.validator = new SimpleReactValidator();
  }
```

The error that I get:

[image]

Is there any way to get this to work?
I did not want to re-write everthing to transform on a class component there's a lot of stuff working fine.

Or maybe another way to validate the fields?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (actual code and not only an image)

Comment: As you are doing it it won't work with functional component, use a class instead because this library is though to work with classes.

Comment: did you try declaring validator as a const ...and passing the const validator as prop?

Comment: @yuri do you know another way to do validations?

Comment: @Ramesh I'm gonna try but how could I use on JSX?

Comment: Why do you have a constructor if you are using a functional component? Which version of React are you using?

Comment: @HerbertIN just pass the validator declared above instead of this.validator

Answer (score 0):

I Re-write the entire code to transform on a class.
:/